# Run @BeforeTest in same thread - paralle run - Selenium webdriver - testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to run test in parallel. My driver is instantiated in base constructor and url and login are done in @BeforeTest.

While running parallel = 'classes', @BeforeClass is not working correctly. Please find link to demo project https://github.com/reactJestuser/DemoParallelRun/tree/master/DemoRun

I am running 2 test in parallel, one browser opens and login credentials are entered twice while for other test only browser is instantiated, url and login details are not entered.

Also, is there any way I can use same session to run test in parallel? so that every time browser is opened, its already logged in.

Answer (score 1):

The `driver variable in Base.java` is static and is not thread safe. It is storing state across instances.  Make it non-static.

Comment: Making driver non-static is not making any difference. I am still facing same issue. 2 browser are opening but login details entered in @BeforeTest and working for one browser only.

Comment: The code for entering login etc is inside the @BeforeSuite method in Base.java. Look at that and move it to a BeforeMethod

Comment: @TesterGG Make the changes as suggested above (make `driver to non-static`). Apart from making it `non-static`, in your `Base constructor`, do not call `setupChromeDriver()` method explicitly. Instead have `@BeforeClass` annotation for the `setupChromeDriver()` method. Then call `init()` method explicitly from  `setupChromeDriver()` method. It should work in parallel.